# Dynamic table that optimizes block height to fit page or skips to next page if page cutoff overlap

Tags: tables, formatting, margins, programming, printing

Say I have a bunch of blocks in a table like this:

```
|251|haf|p24|<-- 251 block
|251|dga|63y|
|251|hla|asp|
|364|fty|p24|<-- 364 block
|765|sfn|alr|<-- 765 block
|765|hdf|hrt|
|765|fjg|jth|
|765|wrs|63y|
|999|hla|asp|<-- 999 block
|999|haf|p24|
|999|dga|63y|
-------------
|999|hla|asp|
|999|haf|p24|
|999|dga|63y|
|999|hla|asp|
```

Notice how the blocks are grouped by the first column. Here the line indicates the page cutoff mark, which happens to overlap block 999. I want a way to order these blocks like this:

```
|251|haf|p24| (PAGE 1)
|251|dga|63y|
|251|hla|asp|
|364|fty|p24|
|765|sfn|alr|
|765|hdf|hrt|
|765|fjg|jth|
|765|wrs|63y|



-------------
|999|hla|asp| (PAGE 2)
|999|haf|p24|
|999|dga|63y|
|999|hla|asp|
|999|haf|p24|
|999|dga|63y|
|999|hla|asp|
.
.
.
```

So that blocks grouped by id are not cut off by the page cutoff when this is printed out. Is there something like this that LaTeX can offer?

If it helps, programmatically, I have a tool I've made that can match the ids in the first column to true/false values like so:

```
251 => true
251 => true
251 => true
364 => false
765 => true
765 => true
765 => true
765 => true
999 => false
999 => false
999 => false
999 => false
999 => false
999 => false
999 => false
```

Comment: if each of your blocks are less than page height you just need to make it a series of `tabular` with the each tabular having all the entries in the first column with the same id, and it will naturally fill as many as possible on each page.